# control over To field of MFMailComposeViewController

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

My question is on `MFMailComposeViewController`.
I have a database in a remote location with information about the users, including their email id.

In `MFMailComposeViewController`, when user types the email address in "To" field and after composing the email send it. Then I have to check whether the user's email id is registered or not.

If yes then send the email, if not then show the toast message.

The address mentioned in "To" field must match with an email address in the database.

Also I have to disable cc/bcc field of `MFMailComposeViewController`.

See the image below

Any idea how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remove BCC/CC Field.

There is very little you can change about the look of this dialog.